# Storing encrypted value in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, encryption, secret-key, android-backup-service

I have signed up for the [Android Backup Service](https://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html?csw=1), and have been given a key to put in my AndroidManifest.xml. My application is open source, but I do not want to have the key publicly visible in my repository. How should I encrypt the key so that is decryptable only in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My application is open source, but I do not want to have the key publicly visible in my repository.

Put the key in a string resource, in a separate resource file (e.g., `res/values/omg_do_not_commit_this_to_the_repo.xml`). Then, do not commit that file to the repo (e.g., if you are using Git, add the file to `.gitignore`).

Answer (score 2):

`AndroidManifest.xml` does not support any form of encryption for your keys. You should simply not check it into the public repository to prevent it from being shared

Comment: Would it be possible to have the AndroidManifest reference an encrypted value in strings.xml?